# Spring boot basic application: field NotesRepository required a bean of type 'com.demo.NotesRepository' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**TLDR: I'm playing around with a simple Spring Boot application that doesnt seem to work and throws two kinds of errors depending on how I run it:**

1) **Claiming that the repo bean was not found:**

```
Field notesRepository in com.demo.service.CreateNoteService required a bean of type 'com.demo.models.NotesRepository' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'learnk8s.io.demo.models.NotesRepository' in your configuration.
```

2) **So I shifted all the subpackages into the main package that contains the application class:** 
[image]

**so now the SECOND error that replaced it was the `localhost:8080` page loads nothing (404 error).**

**Main body below >>>**

The overall package structure is like so:

[image]

My code for the service:

```
@Slf4j
@Transactional
@Service
public class CreateNoteService implements NoteService {

    @Autowired
    NotesRepository notesRepository;

    @Override
    public void saveNote(String description, Model model) {
        // Check input
        if(description != null && !description.trim().isEmpty()) {
            notesRepository.save(new Note(null, description.trim()));
            log.info("Saved note successfully");
            //After publish you need to clean up the textarea
            model.addAttribute("description", "");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void getAllNotes(Model model) {
        List<Note> notes = notesRepository.findAll();
        Collections.reverse(notes);
        model.addAttribute("notes", notes);
    }
}
```

And code for the repository (using mongoDb):

```
@Repository
public interface NotesRepository extends MongoRepository<Note, String> {
}
```

Code for my controller class:

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class NoteController {

    @Autowired
    CreateNoteService createNoteService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        createNoteService.getAllNotes(model);
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/note")
    public String saveNotes(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file,
                            @RequestParam String description, @RequestParam(required = false) String publish, @RequestParam(required = false) String upload, Model model) throws IOException {
        if (publish != null && publish.equals("Publish")) {
            createNoteService.saveNote(description, model);
            createNoteService.getAllNotes(model);
            return "redirect:/";
        }
// After save fetch all notes again
        return "index";
    }

}
```

And lastly, the main application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.demo.controller", "com.demo.models", "com.demo.service"})
public class MainJavaApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MainJavaApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

I cant see where i went wrong in ensuring all dependencies were duly autowired and used accordingly, plus all are under the same main package. Am I missing something here? I'm thinking since the service, model and repo layers are all in the same main package, i shouldnt even need to add `@ComponentScan` right? Thanks!

Continued:

The flagged out bean, NotesRepository has been added thru its package by `@ComponentScan{...}` but that doesnt seem to work either.

**EDIT 2:**

I tried shifting all the packages into the Main application package like so:

[image]

Now the spring boot app runs successfully, but when I run localhost:8080 on chrome i get a Whitelabel Error Page:

[image]

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Nope it is not. Refer to EDIT 2 to see the new error thanks!

Comment: what does the application log when you try GET by browser?

Comment: You are now having a new problem, not related to your original issue. Please open a separate question for this

Comment: Also, it looks like @MichaelKreutz suggestion helped you. I would consider upvoting his answer, and selecting his response as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `@ComponentScan` as long as all the components are in subpackages of where your `MainJavaApplication` is. Please move `MainJavaApplication` to root package (I guess `com.demo` in your case).

Can you try adding `@EnableJpaRepositories` in `MainJavaApplication`? Most likely you will also need `@EntityScan`..

Answer (score 0):

what does your MainJavaApplication look like? If you're not specifying the package to be scanned, the ApplicationContext won't be able to create the beans at the start-up time and as a result wouldn't be injectable.

Comment: Have added in my MainJavaApplication class in the question, thanks! I'm curious, doesnt @SpringBootApplication handle mass component scanning already?

Comment: it does, but only the packages accessible from where it stands, I see you made the edit, so should be clear by now